# Combine the value of the variables into one with a new line after first variable

Tags: merge

I have below two variables:
$var1 which has value like

```
ABC
XYZ
SDF
```

and $var 2 which has value like

```
SDF
SGDGH
hfg
```

I want the output like

```
ABC
XYZ
SDF
SDF
SGDGH
hfg
```

I have the below script and i want to merger the value of file_import_2 and file_import_3 into one.

```
    file_import_2=""
    file_import_3=""
    for DataBase in $(< "$1"); do

    file_import_1=`grep -iw "CRQ_DI_PROD_$DataBase" "$Import_List_File" | grep -i prod`;
    if [[ "$file_import_1" = GDH_* ]]; then
    file_import_2=$file_import_1

    fi
    if [[ "$file_import_1" != GDH_* ]]; then
    file_import_3=$DataBase
    fi

var3=$(printf '%s\n%s\n' "$file_import_2" "$file_import_3")
echo $var3

    done
```

The file i am passing to the script and Import_List_File have 4 values each

```
FARP_DATA_111
TRIN_STAGING
DBH
PRS
```

With the print f solution, output is:

```
CRQ_DI_PROD_FARP_DATA_111
CRQ_DI_PROD_TRIN_STAGING
CRQ_DI_PROD_TRIN_STAGING DBH
CRQ_DI_PROD_TRIN_STAGING PRS
```

Comment: It's a variable

Comment: Have you tried `printf "%s\n" "$var1" "$var2"` ?

Comment: yes getting the same output mentioned in the edit .

Comment: First two are fine then i m getting like this in one line CRQ_DI_PROD_TRIN_STAGING DBH
CRQ_DI_PROD_TRIN_STAGING PRS 
instead of just DBH and PRS

Comment: **always** double-quote your variables to prevent shell from word-splitting etc them (e.g. to retain the LF characters).  e.g. `file_import_2="$file_import_1"` and `file_import_3="$DataBase"`.  Ditto for command substitution, e.g. `var3="$(printf '%s\n' "$file_import_2" "$file_import_3")"`.    See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Provided the double quotes as suggested , but still getting the same result.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with below?
file_import_2=""
file_import_3=""

Comment: what? you want to set them to an empty string?

Comment: Yes..I mean i have initialized them to null in the beginning

Comment: that's ok.  you need to double-quote variables when you *use* them.  e.g. `foo="$bar"`.     If there's any chance that the right-hand-side of an assignment might contain whitespace or shell meta-characters (like `&`) then you need to quote the RHS, with either single-quotes (for literal, fixed, static text) or double-quotes (if you want variable expansion, command substitution, etc to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' "$var1" "$var2"
ABC
XYZ
SDF
SDF
SGDGH
hfg
```

To assign that to another variable: `var3=$(printf '%s\n%s\n' "$var1" "$var2")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I added the code you sent to my sample script and i am getting a little different value. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: btw, this doesn't need two `%s\n`s in the printf format string.  printf will loop over args if there are more than are needed by the fmt.

Comment: Thanks cas, I didn't think of that.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was bash or GNU coreutils only but it's "standard". in the [posix printf spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) it says "*9. The format operand shall be reused as often as necessary to satisfy the argument operands. .......*"